# How to save git in a specific local folder?

Tags: git

I am new in the use of git and github ( learning)

Whenever I type " git init " in git bash, it save to a file that I don't wanna use ( desktop/asus) . I want to use it in an specific folder that I have created with a name "github"

how can I that ? its keep saving the git file in that asus folder. I have tried to change my visual studio (community version) path but still it doesn't work

Comment: it is important in which directory you are when you invoke `git init`.

Comment: if you need more info please copy paste whole content of your terminal first, since your question lacks details.

Comment: What do you mean by "it save to a file"?  `git init` should create a .git directory in the current working directory.  If you want to initialize a particular directory to be a new git repository, run `git init` from that directory.

Comment: As other people said : you should run `git init` while located in the correct directory. If you need directions on how to navigate to the correct location from a terminal (more precisely: from `git-bash`), please update your question.

Comment: Also note that Visual Studio has a "Git mode" where it thinks it knows more than you do (which might be true in your case, but this interferes with using any web tutorials that *don't* expect you to be using VS). You need to decide whether you want to learn "how to use VS (and Git within it)" or "how to use Git" (and then separately, probably later, "how to use VS").

Answer (score 1):

`If the $GIT_DIR environment variable is set then it specifies a path to use instead of ./.git for the base of the repository.` - [Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init)

Normally, git will init in the folder you invoke the command. But you should check for `$GIT_DIR` environment variable if it existed